# Saturn-like rings node in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, textures, scenekit, scnnode

I am creating a model of Saturn and I'm having problems when creating the rings. I found this asset

[image]

but when I try to set it as a diffuse, it projects like this

[image]

How can I control the way a texture projects over a geometry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. By replacing the cylinder with a torus and rotating the image 90 degrees, XCode did the mapping itself.

[image]

But there must be a better way.

Comment: The best way is really what works best for you without jumping to more hoops. Personally I’d prefer to use the way I described in lthe ast sentence of my answer, i,e. get a texture of the complete rings rather than a section that is repeated. The cylinder is on top (and bottom) mapped like a regular plane and therefor a simple square texture (of the right size) will do. That said, your solution is totally acceptable.

Comment: how are you controlling the height of this torus? I'm getting a gigantic torus surrounding the whole sphere, instead of a flat ring like yours

Comment: how did you do that ? I used Tube But still having problem like yours

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t specifically a SceneKit or IOS issue, the same would apply in any 3D package.

You can control the way a texture projects over a geometry by using **UV mapping**. In practice that means you map the vertices and faces of the model on to the texture in software such a Blender. The texture you use now is meant to be tiled but because the lines on the texture are perfectly straight it will never look optimal.

To save yourself some trouble, use a texture that shows the entire ring from the top/above.

Comment: I can see that UV mapping is a constant. How can I use it to achieve the desired projection?

Comment: Basically every vertex in the model has a UV coordinate on a normalized scale that represents a position in the texture you use. So all UV coords are between 0,0 and 1,1. The primitives included in scenekit like the SCNCylinder and SCNTorus generate these UV coords automatically. If you want to use different UV coordinates (and thus project the texture differentlly on the model) you will have to use a third party package to map the vertices of the model to a 2D texture.

Comment: that's solve my problem (using 3d Model of Saturn Ring)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use SCNTube.

Comment: I used Tube But there is a problem with that

Comment: I used tube as you write here but still this problem is exist how can I solve that ? I rotate 90 degrees the image But still there is problem with that